# Explicit form for sum of "multichoose" functions.

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I have to draw $k$ balls from a set of $n$ balls with replacement, but without order. It is known that the number of ways to do that is given by
$$
\binom{n+k-1}{k}.
$$
**Question:** Does there exist an explicit form for the number of combinations to draw $\ell$ or less balls, i.e.
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\ell}\binom{n+k-1}{k}.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$
\sum_{k=1}^{\ell}\binom{n+k-1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\ell}\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}=\sum_{i=n}^{n+\ell-1} \binom{i}{n-1}=\sum_{i=n-1}^{n+\ell-1}\binom{i}{n-1}-1
$$

Using the [Hockey Stick Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity), we know that $$\sum_{i=n-1}^{n+\ell-1}\binom{i}{n-1} =\binom{n+\ell}{n}$$
So the answer is $$\binom{n+\ell}{n}-1$$

Comment: Great! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Choosing $l$ or fewer balls from $n$ is the same as choosing exactly $l$ balls from $n+1$, then throwing away any copies of the last ball, except that this includes the case of having $0$ balls left, and you don't want to count that. So your answer is (number of ways to choose $l$ from $n+1$)$-1$.